# Building in-house infrastructure for web hosting

Tags: web-hosting

We want to develop an e-commerce website and for the start it will have my suppliers which is 800 000 to a million (fixed) each holding an account just like e mail. The member customers after ads would be 5-7 million and non member customers around 5 million example. Now, the 18 web pages are currently designed on word with giving them hyperlinks.

We want to set it up in-house (we want to host the website ourselves) and are seeking advice for infrastructure needed from the start. At the moment we require just the basic infrastructure to fill out just the requirements. We can expand it later. We have no idea and its so very confusing what web server can we use etc etc....

My operating system is Linux and my web server software is Apache.

Comment: "I need serious help." - then I suggest you pay serious money and pay someone to assist.

Comment: If you want to launch a commercial platform and "have no idea" you ***ABSOLUTELY MUST*** hire a professional sysadmin -- ServerFault **is not** a substitute for competent personnel taking care of your infrastructure, and if you actually intend to charge folks for using your system/product you owe it to your customers and yourself to ensure that there is a team in place who can design a good infrastructure and keep things running.

Comment: This question is way too general.  Try providing more details about the application you are building and why you think you want to host it yourself.  Also try to limit the scope of each question to specific technologies or benefits.  The actual answer to this question done correctly would be several pages of text and depends on variables not provided currently.

Comment: You're designing a website intended to serve 10+ million users in Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's a good idea to get an expert that helps you with that project. It is very hard to make recommendations for such a huge thing. This should be planed very well or you will run in to serious problems later which my force you to start from scratch again. Storage, HA, Network etc. all have to work together.

For VHosting there is an open source project called virtualmin which sits on top of webmin and lets you set up a hosting server for multiple domains.